# How do I specify base url for REST API tests with WebTau

Tags: java, rest, groovy, automated-tests, webtau

In [WebTau documentation](https://testingisdocumenting.org/webtau/HTTP/CRUD) on how to test CRUD, examples are using relative urls

```
def customerPayload = [firstName: "FN", lastName: "LN"]

def id = http.post("/customers", customerPayload) {
    return id
}

http.get("/customers/${id}") {
    body.should == customerPayload
}
```

How do I set base url to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using [Groovy standalone runner](https://testingisdocumenting.org/webtau/groovy-standalone-runner/introduction) you can base url via command line

```
webtau --url=http://localhost:8080
```

or have a groovy config file `webtau.cfg.groovy`

```
url = "http://localhost:8080
```

In case of Java `src/test/resources/webtau.properties` file

```
url = http://localhost:8080
```

or pass it via system property for test execution

```
-Durl="http://localhost:8080"
```

for both Java and Groovy you can also provide base url via environment variable

```
WEBTAU_URL=http://localhost:8080
```